# Why does attempting to autofit the width of a sheet, or a single column on that sheet, fail?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, column-width

I have one column whose contents are truncated, and I'd like to avoid having to 2-click the right column gutter to see the data. First I tried autofitting the entire shebang:

```
private void PopulatePivotTableDataSheet()
{
    if (null == _produceUsagePivotDataList) return;
    AddColumnHeadingRowPivotData();
    foreach (ProduceUsagePivotData pupd in _produceUsagePivotDataList)                
    {
        AddPivotData(pupd.ItemCode, pupd.ItemDescription, pupd.Unit, pupd.MonthYear, pupd.Quantity,
            pupd.TotalPrice, pupd.IsContractItem);
    }
    _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells.AutoFit();
}
```

...but the last line fails with "AutoFit method of Range class failed"

Then I tried applying it to just the column in question like so:

```
private void AddPivotData(String ItemCode, String ItemDescription, String Unit, String MonthYear, int Quantity, Decimal TotalPrice, Boolean IsContractItem)
{
    var itemCodeCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[_lastRowAddedPivotTableData + 1, 1];
    itemCodeCell.Value2 = ItemCode;

    var itemDescriptionCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[_lastRowAddedPivotTableData + 1, 2];
    itemDescriptionCell.Value2 = ItemDescription;
    itemDescriptionCell.AutoFitWidth(); 
    . . .
```

...and that last line fails with, "'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'AutoFitWidth'"

What in Sam Hill o' beans is going on here? Autofitting should be easily doable, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try  `_xlPivotDataSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();`

Comment: That worked; make it an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will apply AutoFit to the columns comprising the range:

```
_xlPivotDataSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```